# Href to download and onclick to anchor link

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way (I wouldn't be too surprised) or maybe it's just not possible. I have links that when clicked on, download a file. I would also like to have these links show a lightbox. I can easily get them to do one or the other, but not both. The links are also being created through asp. The code I have right now:

```
<asp:Label id=Label1 EnableViewState="False" runat="server" Text='<%# "<A  id=""launcher"" class=""track"" Href="""&amp;DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Url")&amp;""">"&amp;DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Name")&amp;"</A>" %>'>
</asp:Label>
```

Within the `<A>`, I have tried: `onclick=""test();return false;""`, the same thing except with `onclientclick`, with and without the `return false;` (also tried `true`).

The function I have:

```
function test() {
  window.location.href="#feature";
}
```

Problem is that it never does the onclick event. I tried putting a breakpoint at that spot, which gets hit when I click the link, but I never see the content that should be displayed. Is what I'm trying to do even possible, this way or some other way?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hk3Wd/6/. This is behaving slightly differently than on the website I'm working on. On the website, the lightbox shows but no download. In that fiddle, the download starts but not lightbox.

Comment: What does the output look like for your link?

Comment: Is this what you're after?:

`<a onclick="test();return true;" id="launcher" class="track" href="http://correctlinkishere.exe">Text</a>`

Comment: OK, what do you mean by " I would also like to have these links show a lightbox." if you're downloading a file?

Comment: When the link is clicked, I want 2 things to happen: 1) The file starts to download, and 2)the lightbox opens. The lightbox contains content separate from the download.

Comment: You need to target the download to a new window: target="_blank"

Comment: Well that kind of helped.  Adding that, does fix part of the link problem. And it also made me catch an error in the lightbox JS code. Although now that that's fix, now the lightbox shows (albeit with an error inside) but now the download doesn't fire.

Comment: Please post a small example on jsfiddle.net..

Comment: Add an alert to test(), you'll see that it fires fine.

Comment: Yes, it is. But it should be showing a lightbox and it's not. The lightbox needs that id="launcher" to be passed and I suspect that it's not when doing it through the onclick event. Not sure what to do about that.

Comment: IDs must be unique. You're using "launcher" twice. You many want to clean this up a bit and post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some suggestions from Diodeus and others found online, I have figured this out.

Diodeus was correct in that I had two instances of `id=launcher`, one of which was unnecessary. I removed that.

The other was in the way Fancybox seems to work. It uses the href attribute to determine what to fill the frame with. In this case href was set to a file (exe), so it was trying to display the executable in the lightbox frame rather than actually downloading it.

To fix this, I set the `onclick` of the `<a>` tag to a JS function. That function:

```
function test() {
   $("a.launcher").trigger("click");
}
```

Within my hidden div, I added:

```
<a class="launcher" href="#ads"></a>
```

Basically, the onclick calls the function which triggers the hidden link which launches the lightbox.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FjgRw/1/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your "double" double quotes are the issue. This works

```
<a href='test.php' onclick='test();return false;'>click me!</a>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function test() {
    window.location.href="#feature";
}
</script>
```